# Equality of angles in Visual Differential Geometry and forms, page xix

Tags: geometry

Tristan Needham's book, Visual Differential Geometry and Forms is wonderful with lots of diagrams.  Early on (p. xix of the preface) he tries to use Newton's "synthetic method of fluxions" to prove

$T = \mbox{tan} \theta \implies dT/d\theta = 1 + T^2 $

Looking at the diagram given I see do not see that angle $\theta$ in the big triangle is the same as angle $\theta$ in the little one.

Any ideas?

Comment: As most people here don't have that book, it would be advisable to post a photo of the page you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Observe that since $\theta+\alpha+\pi/2=\pi$ in the big triangle, and the sides of the big triangle and the small one are aligned, necessarily the angle of the small triangle must be $\theta$